# The browse directive inexplicably chokes on URLs

Tags: stata

According to Stata's `SMCL` pdf documentation for the `{browse args:text}` directive:

> *Example*
>   . . . you can {browse "http://www.stata.com":visit the Stata website} . . .

However:

```
. di "you can {browse "http://www.stata.com":visit the Stata website} "
you can {browse http:/ invalid name
r(198);
```

Likewise:

```
. di as smcl "you can {browse "http://www.stata.com":visit the Stata website} "
you can {browse http:/ invalid name
r(198);
```

I am using Stata 15.1 on Linux and on macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use double quotes:

```
. display `"you can {browse "http://www.stata.com":visit the Stata website}"'
you can visit the Stata website
```